# Matlab load .mat data with nested sturcture

Tags: matlab

I need to read a .mat database that contains a structure as below:

`Database1.(Condition).(clip_number).data`

There are 60 clips in the condition that I need. I have tried `data = load('file.mat', 'Database1.Condition1.clip1')`

But seems the only valid variable I could access is `Database1`. So, how could I load the data I need? Please note that I have no experience in Matlab before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a `.mat` file in Matlab, you can only select the top-level variable(s) to load. It's not like a document or JSON database where you can index into it deeply at load time.

So do this to grab `Database1`:

```matlab
s = load('file.mat', 'Database1');
```

And then grab the individual clips from it:

```matlab
myClip1 = s.Database1.Condition1.clip1;
myClip2 = s.Database1.Condition1.clip2;
% ... blah blah blah ...
```

You might want to loop over them:

```matlab
nClips = 60;
for iClip = 1:nClips
   clipFieldName = sprintf('clip%d', iClip);
   myClip = s.Database1.Condition1.(clipFieldName);
   % ... do stuff with that clip ...
   % Maybe store the results in a cell array like this:
   out{iClip} = whateverYouGotFromProcessing(myClip);
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I used a Python package to read it. But I'm glad to see it in the Matlab way.